# Access generated thumbnails

Tags: media

Is it possible to allow my editors to access the generated media thumbnails within the media library?

So for example, when a user selects an image, they should be able to also select the thumbnail size that should be used:

[image]

Comment: In what context? Normally when adding an image you can already do this.

Comment: Currently I am trying to select a social network specific image using the plugin blog2social, but I assume this can be seens as a general question due to the fact that I ain't got the option to chose a thumbnail size right in my media library. I only can select a thumbnail size after inserting an image into a post.